# Назначение клавиш пользователем

Tags: javascript

Нашёл на одном сайте такую приколюху, что пользователь может изменять назначение каждой клавиши - как ему удобно и мне бы хотелось сделать подобное на своём сайте, но нигде информации об этом не нашёл. Вот и возникает вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам мог изменять назначение каждой клавиши и, если ему это будет не удобно, он мог сбросить значения по умолчанию? Буду рад вашей помощи :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хмм... ну мой вариант будет не идеальным, но минимальную демонстрацию обеспечит.

Тут наверно главная фишка в том, чтобы знать про `keyup`, который умеет определять нажатую кнопку. Изначально персонаж настроен двигаться направо и налево при нажатии правой и левой стрелок. Изменение происходит сразу при введении любой другой кнопки в инпуты (не заморачивался с кнопкой 'ok'):

[JsFiddle ДЕМО](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/qjca7dve/)

```js
(function(){

const bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');
let left = 0; //Изначально позиция 0

//Кнопки, нажатие которых будем сравнивать перед действием
let RMove = 'ArrowRight'; 
let LMove = 'ArrowLeft';

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  //Создаем регулярные выражения, с которыми будем сравнивать нажатую кнопку, 
  //Которую можно получить через "e.key"
  let RMoveKey = new RegExp( RMove, 'ig' );
  let LMoveKey = new RegExp( LMove, 'ig' );
  
  //При нажатии кнопки сравнили - если совпало с заранее сохраненной кнопкой - 
  //Обновляем значение позиции left и сдвигаем куда надо.
  if( e.key.match( RMoveKey ) ) {
    left += 50;
    bubu.style.left = left + 'px';
  }
  if( e.key.match( LMoveKey ) ) {
    left -= 50;
    bubu.style.left = left + 'px';
  }
});

document.getElementById('ChangeR').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  //А при введении новой кнопки, просто обновляем изначальное значение 
  //Переменной, в которой должна храниться сравниваемая кнопка.
  RMove = e.key;
  document.querySelector('#ChangeR + span').innerHTML = 'Теперь персонаж будет передвигаться направо с помощью кнопки <span style="color: red;">' + e.key + '</span>';
});

document.getElementById('ChangeL').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  LMove = e.key;  
  document.querySelector('#ChangeL + span').innerHTML = 'Теперь персонаж будет передвигаться налево с помощью кнопки <span style="color: red;">' + e.key + '</span>';
});

})();
```

```css
/* Ненужная декорация */
#bubu {width: 50px; height: 50px; background: orange; border-radius: 50%; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<div id="bubu">o_o</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<input id="ChangeR" placeholder="Движение направо"><span></span><br><br>
<input id="ChangeL" placeholder="Движение налево"><span></span>
```

keypress тоже умеет подобное, но не все кнопки умеет определять.

Comment: Спасибо за пример! Попробую на нём что-то сделать :)